# Override Django allauth template with extra form

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-allauth

I want to override the allauth email confirm page with my own.

I managed to render my own template by creating a file called `email_confirm.html` in `templates/account/`.

It works fine but I want another form there. I found a post to override view from another app:

- [How to override a view from an external Django app](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19777151073/how-to-override-a-view-from-an-external-django-app)

But this does not work very well for the allauth app since it expects some variables to render the template correctly.

It there a way that I can pass the form to that template? Or that I can extend the allauth view without completely overwriting the existing view?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the original **email_confirm.html** to your location on **templates/account/**, and add your form over there.

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/email_confirm.html

Comment: That's what I did but the form won't display because it's not in the view that calls the template...

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) suggests adding a setting to your settings.py file.

> ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS (=None)
>       A string pointing to a custom form class (e.g. ‘myapp.forms.SignupForm’) that is used during signup to ask the user
>   for additional input (e.g. newsletter signup, birth date). This class
>   should implement a def signup(self, request, user) method, where user
>   represents the newly signed up user.

All you need to do is add this setting to your settings.py file.